# Property "Pages" does not contain support for type PageContentCollection

Tags: wpf

I get the following error on the second line of the code below:

The error is:
Property "Pages" does not contain support for type PageContentCollection.

Here is my complete code:

```
 <FixedDocument Name="customerReport">

        <PageContent>
           <FixedPage>
            <Label FontSize="20" Margin="100,20,0,0">REPORT</Label>            
            <ListView  BorderThickness="0" Margin="50,100,0,0" FontSize="14" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
              <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridReport">             

                  <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <Label/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <Label/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
              </ListView.View>
            </ListView>        

          </FixedPage>   
        </PageContent>





      </FixedDocument>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out it is a known bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=293646